# Read multiple text files in a folder and import to database

Tags: java, mysql

I need to import bunch of text files(292) into different database. Each file has to be in different table and database. It will retrieve doc_no and doc_cde from table sys_doc. My idea is to use a loop. Also wondering how could I filter this text files according to their database,based on the doc_cde.

This is the sample of code I think I will use right now. Any other ideas to do my task will be helpful.

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class automateImport
{
   public static void main(String[] args) 
   {
       DBase db = new DBase();
       Connection conn = db.connect("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test","root","caspian");
       db.importData(conn,args[0]);
   }

}

class DBase
{
    public DBase(){}

    public Connection connect(String db_connect_str, 
    String db_userid, String db_password)
    {
        Connection conn;
        try
        {
           Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();

            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(db_connect_str, 
            db_userid, db_password);

        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            conn = null;
        }

        return conn;    
    }

    public void importData(Connection conn,String filename)
    {
        Statement stmt;
        String query;

        try
        {
            stmt = conn.createStatement(
            ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE,
            ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);

            query = "LOAD DATA INFILE '"+filename+
                     "' INTO TABLE testtable (text,price);";

            stmt.executeUpdate(query);

        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            stmt = null;
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: ..think to format your code, it is really important :)

Comment: you want to store only the file names, the whole file (binary) or the file content (text)?

Comment: the file content, the data in the text file

Comment: "Each file has to be in different table and database" - That would require you to create a new database, then switch to it and create a new table per file. Have a look at the mysql jdbc documentation on how to switch databases (afaik "use mydatabase" is discouraged).

Comment: Hi Thomas, what if the database and and the tables in the database already exist in MySQL Workbench. Do I have to create it again? I just want to insert the text file into it respective database. Sorry in need of exposure because really confusing

Comment: how do you determine the mapping between file and table?

Comment: Dear Charan, the doc.code is use to match with the text file while the doc.no is used to identify the database name. There are 2 database currently (e.g: c01 & c02). The program will retrieve the doc.no and doc.code from a table sys_doc